# Select only If column name is not Null

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have two table

Table1 - `tblEmployee`

```
 EmployeeId      ContactInfoID
   1001            1
   1002            2
```

Table2 - `tblContactInfo`

```
    ContactInfoID  FirstName MiddleName LastName
     1                Ram     Prasad     Dhakal
     2                Hari    Null        Rai
```

Here I want to Select `FirstName, MiddleName, LastName` only if that is not `Null`.If I select `EmployeeID=1001` then `FirstName, MiddleName, LastName` should be selected and if `EmployeeID = 1002` only `FirstName` and `LastName` should be selected.

I tried this code

```
SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName
FROM `tblemployee` AS E INNER JOIN 
`tblcontactinfo` AS C 
ON E.ContactInfoID= C.ContactInfoID
WHERE E.EmployeeID= 1001
AND MiddleName is null;
```

But I am not getting required result. Which query should I use?

Comment: You can conditionally select rows but you cannot conditionally select columns. AND your query will not find any rows because 1001 middlename is not null.

Comment: Can you post the output you want